# Is there a way to have two simultaneous maven builds populate one local repo without collisions

Tags: maven, repository

I'd like to run two maven builds in parallel on my local system and have them populate the same maven repository.   Both are mostly building things I didn't change and writing snapshots.  Is there a way to get them to use lock files etc to avoid one reading while the over's writing?

I know I can use set my local repo location and have /.m2/a/repository /.m2/b/repository but is there an interleaving solution?

Or would this merely get me in to loads of trouble with no real upside?

Thanks

Peter

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I believe the goal is to have two source trees with two modifications and build/test them at the same time

Comment: In this case you'd still want to separate them somehow. Otherwise you wouldn't know which artifact belongs to which project. So I don't think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.  Settings a private repository for each build seems to be provide the benefit of keeping the builds separate while allowing the user to work on multiple issues simultaneously.

Modify settings to use an environment variable for the local repo

```
<localRepository>${MY_REPO}</localRepository>
```

Workflow:
Checkout source workspace A
Set Variable MY_REPO workspaceA/repo
Make change
Start maven command to build and test

Repeat for workspace B

This would be useful if the build & test phase were long and the multiple test instance were unlikely to interact.

Peter